# How do I remove the white lines in the colorbar legend in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, heatmap

I make a heatmap with the package ComplexHeatmap, but when i zoom in the figure, the colorbar shows a orrible white lines, like this:

[Colorbar with orrible white lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p9Bs.jpg)

I tried jpeg, tiff and pdf.....same result when i zoom in the figure.

Here the code to draw sample my colorbar:

```
col_princ <- circlize::colorRamp2(breaks = c(1, 5, 9),
                              colors = c("red", "yellow", "green"))
lgd <- Legend(title =  "Legend",
          title_position = "topcenter",
          at = seq(1,9,1),
          col_fun = col_princ,
          legend_width = unit(18, "cm"),
          direction = "horizontal",
          labels_gp = gpar(fontsize = 10),
          nr = 1)
draw(lgd, just="center", x=unit(12,"cm"), y=unit(10, "cm"))
```

Thank you very much, i'm blocked

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. I cannot reproduce the horrible white lines, please consider changing your code and adding (dummy) data towards a minimal reproducible example that shows the horrible white lines.

Comment: Thanks teunbrand, i modifiy my question.